# Function which receives a 1 d array and print its value there?

Tags: c, linux, function

I wanted to write a function which can receive a 1-D array and print its value there.Also wanted to know how 2-D array can be received by a function and print its value there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C you pass arrays by pointers, and usually a second parameter, which contains its length.

For Example: `void printArray(char * arrayStart, int length)` (for a char array)
and I assume you know how to write a simple for-loop to iterate over all elements of your array and print them. For 2D Arrays you would use `char ** arrayStart`instead.

(When calling the function you pass the array in the following fashion:

```
char myArray[] = "some Text"
printArray(myArray, 9);
```

)

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have a question.Can we pass the complete array as shown below.suppose we want to pass integer array .cant it be written as shown below void printarray( int param[10] )

Comment: @kadu Unfortunately not, as an array in C does not know its own size, and the way you are suggesting does not work, due to the fact, that internally `param[10]` is actually changed to `param + 10` (param being the pointer to the first element of the array), so in order to avoid confusion, this way of passing arrays is not allowed. While it is a bit inconvenient, once you get used to, it is not that bad (and pointers are really useful for a lot of things)

Answer (score 0):

sample code here:

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    void print_1D(int *arr,int m)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
            printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    void print_2D(int *arr[num],int m,int n) //<---observe here
    {
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int oneD[anySize1] = {2,5,67,23,32,....};   
        int twoD[anySize2][num] = { {23,17,..},{....},{....},....}; //<---and here  
        int m = anySize1,n = anySize2;
        print_1D(oneD,m);
        print_2D(twoD,m,n);
        return 0;
    }
```

if 2d is array is declared like this

```
    int arr2D[10][20];
```

then function declaration must be,

```
    void print_2D(int *arr[20],int m,int n)
```

or

```
    void print_2D(int arr[][20],int m,int n)
```

Comment: the line `int m = n1, n = n2` should be `int m = anySize1, n = anySize2` to avoid confusion. (I'd also prefer to use `int ** arr` instead of `int * are[num]` as i find it less confusing)